# Cassandra cqlsh not running - Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves'

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cqlsh, six

Cassandra's `cqlsh` is not running. When I am running `cqlsh`, I am getting the following error in the terminal. It was working before! It's weird that it was working till yesterday. Note that I'm able to start Cassandra server with `./bin/cassandra` command.

My Cassandra version: 4.1.3
My OS: macOS Sonoma (Silicon)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/senthilnayagan/Developer/Infra/apache-cassandra-4.1.3/bin/cqlsh.py", line 134, in <module>
    from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
  File "/Users/senthilnayagan/Developer/Infra/apache-cassandra-4.1.3/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.25.0.zip/cassandra-driver-3.25.0/cassandra/cluster.py", line 33, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves'
```

Also, I tried running `cqlsh` with multiple versions of Cassandra (4.1.3 and 4.1.4), but I'm still getting the same error below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: could you add the output of running `python -V` & `nodetool status` to your question? CQL shell depends on Python and I wonder if there is something going on there.

Comment: $ python3 -V
Python 3.12.2


$ ./nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  138.6 KiB  16      100.0%            43dd5424-59a7-43cf-9f29-9bde39baca8d  rack1

Answer (score 0):

On my M2, when I try to run cqlsh with Python 3.12, I see this error as well:

```
  File "/Users/aaron.ploetz/local/apache-cassandra-4.1.3/bin/cqlsh.py", line 134, in <module>
    from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
  File "/Users/aaron.ploetz/local/apache-cassandra-4.1.3/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.25.0.zip/cassandra-driver-3.25.0/cassandra/cluster.py", line 33, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves'
```

When I switch back to 3.9.6, I see this:

```
Connected to Aarons Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042
[cqlsh 6.1.0 | Cassandra 4.1.3 | CQL spec 3.4.6 | Native protocol v5]
Use HELP for help.
aaron@cqlsh>
```

Basically, downgrade to Python 3.9 and it should work.

Note: You can also use something like [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage multiple versions of Python.